# What is the probability that a student is learning just one language?

Tags: probability

This is my three events probability problem.

Consider events:

- $E$: Student learning Spanish
- $F$: Student learning French
- $A$: Student learning German

The associated probabilities are:
$$
P(E)=0.28 \quad P(F) = 0.26 \quad P(A) = 0.16 \\
P(E \cap F) = 0.12 \quad P(E \cap A) = 0.04 \quad P(F \cap A) = 0.06 \\
P(E \cap F \cap A) = 0.02
$$
What are the chances of a student learning just one language?

**What I did:** first I found $P(E \cup F \cup A)= 0.5 $.

Now I know that I have to substact the intersection out of the union. That means, $0.5-0.12-0.04-0.06=0.28$. the thing is that the correct answer is $0.32$. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know how to set up Venn diagrams?  The problems solves pretty easily from one.

Comment: Yes TurkeyHundt, I did set up a Venn diagram, That's how I figured the method I described. My number is still off. Any idea why?

Comment: @AnonBays for formating, see this: https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You subtracted out the P(E n F n A)=0.02 three different times (it is included in each of P(E n F)=0.12, P(E n A)=0.04, P(F n A)=0.06).  So you need to add it back in twice.

Comment: Also, if you have the Venn Diagram setup, you can just add up the parts that are only in one circle.  Which is $0.14+0.10+0.08=0.32$

Answer (score 1):

If you drew a Venn diagram like me, you would have the number learning three languages $0.02$, the number learning exactly two languages $0.10+0.02+0.04$, and the number learning exactly one language $0.14+0.10+0.08$.

[image]

Alternatively:

The number learning at least one language is $0.28+0.26+0.16-0.12-0.04-0.06+0.02$

The number learning at least two languages is $0.12+0.04+0.06-2\times0.02$

So . . .

Comment: Ah thanks, I was actually pretty close with my diagram, my numbers were wrong unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

That's probability that the student talks only one of these. Probability he speaks only Spanish is for example: $P_1=P(E)-P(E\cap F)-P(E\cap G)+P(E\cap F\cap G)$. Do you see why?

Thus the probabilty you're looking for is: $P=P_1+P_2+P_3$

Comment: Wouldnt you have to add back in $P(E\cap G\cap F)$?

Comment: Oh yes you're right! Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh there you go! that's right. Thanks also to turkeyhundt for the additionnal hint. That worked.